# In Xamarin Forms, how can I show a web image in the same way as a image in the resource folder?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms image where I want to show images from the web, kind of like in a facebook style feed. Due to bandwidth concerns, I do not want to serve high resolution images from my web server.

Now if I add a Image with the Source attribute set to my image url, I cannot get the image to display larger than what it is in native resolution (at least on iOS where I am testing now). This means that to display the image at full width on the later iPhones I need to have a image wider than 1000px.

Is there any way I can make the web images behave more like the images loaded from the resource directory, that are scaled up on higher resolution devices?

Not sure how to explain this in a good way, this repo (not mine) addresses the same problem: https://github.com/williamwilling/xamarin-forms-image-size . Probably not a bug in Xamarin forms I would guess, more a behavior.

Note: I only need this to work on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

You really should consider using the library [FFimageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading).

Here is the example from their wiki. And the images behave similar when loading from a Source  / URL. It also allows caching, which is extremely useful.

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
        WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
        DownsampleToViewSize="true"
        Source = "http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg">
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

Comment: I added the library, but I am unable to understand how to get the behavior I want. I have an image that is 400px wide and I want it to show as 320 DIP (device independent pixels) wide. When I use standard Image in xamarin and also for this library the image displays smaller (on high resolution devices).